# Referential constraint violation: invalid Foreign Key value while inserting in teradata

Tags: foreign-keys

tables defined:

```
create set table admin
( 
employee char(36) not null
)
constraint abc Primary key (employee);

create set table user
(
employee char(36) not null
employee_address char(36) not null
)admin(
constraint aaa primary_key(employee,employee address)
constraint cde foreign key(employee) references admin(employee);
```

Issue:

While trying to insert the data in to table User, facing the error

```
Referential constraint violation: invalid Foreign Key value
```

Checked the data and found that the foreign key which is being referenced is present in admin table..

Some help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Hi do you have any information/code on how you are inserting. Progamming language, database type (eg MySQL, SQL Server, PGSQL)? Really need more information in order to be able to help

Comment: I am doing this in teradata and it is a normal insert from another table.I have validated the datatypes and they are same in all the tables.